# How to find row and column of nonzero element in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
Type    All    Fail     Pass
 A       0       0        0
 B       1       0        0
 C       0       0        0
```

Now, I want to get the column name of the nonzero element as well as the corresponding value in the `Type` column. Hence, I want to return `B` and `All` in this case. I know how to return a true/false matrix using this `compare_severity.select_dtypes(include=['number']) != 0`. But I am not sure how to get the column name and row index of the `True` element. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: give `dropna()` a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to find the row where the dataframe is equal to 1, as well as the column where the dataframe is equal to 1. You have to set the Type as the index, to ensure the equality check is focused on the number columns only.

```
df = df.set_index("Type")

df.loc[df.eq(1).any(axis=1),df.eq(1).any()]


       All
Type    
 B      1
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps,

```
df = df.set_index("Type")
result = df.where(df.select_dtypes(include="number") > 0) \
    .fillna("") \
    .to_dict(orient='index')

print({k:i for k, v in result.items() for i, j in v.items() if j})
```

output,

```
{'B': 'All'}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `idxmax` with `dropna` here:

```
num = df.select_dtypes('number')
num.where(num.ne(0)).idxmax().dropna()

All    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Or we can use `np.where` which gives us the index as well:

```
df.columns[np.where(num)[0]].tolist()

['All']
```